# Prestashop. Why layered navigation block dissapear after I click on some category?

Tags: filter, navigation, prestashop, layered

I'm using the theme [Shop-it](http://billionthemes.com/Themes/Detail/2300388/Shop-It) and i'm trying to change the category page adding the layered navigation block. After i hook the block it appears on the category page but after I click on some category and the result is displayed the layered navigation block disappears.

I see that when you click on some category it does a request and when i look at the response it appears that the filterblock variable is empty. But i cannot see why.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a problem with the blocklayered.tpl of the theme. The theme was created using themler and because of that the pages has id's. For some reason the id of the layered theme was no getting pass. So the easy way to fix this is to fix de id on the blocklayered.tpl on the part where the file try to include another with a specific id.